# PHP, Mysqli, how to bind parameters from column and use their

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to select num1 and num2 from different users:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT `num1`, `num2` FROM `Mytable1` WHERE `user` in (SELECT DISTINCT `user` from `Mytable1` where type=2)');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($num1, $num2);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

And I need get results `$result = $num1 * $num2;`

Then enter the result in Mytable2

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `Mytable2` SET `num`=? WHERE `name` in (SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM bookmaker_bets WHERE type=2)');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $result);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

How to make that num1 and num2 selected from each user, and not first user?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this update with one SQL statement:

```
UPDATE table2 
  INNER JOIN users ON users.userId = table2.userId 
  INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.userId = users.userId 
SET table2.result = table1.num1 * table1.num2 
WHERE users.type = 2;
```

Please, refer to [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ecff/2)